# asp net core 1 RC2 AccountController injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core-rc2

I created a asp.net core rc2 web application with user identity, however i'm confused how the account controller class is getting it's arguments, usermanager, signinmanager?  Where are they being passed in from?  I follow the call stack and I get external code, what external code is passing in these objects?  Help me understand, how these 2 objects are being initialized.

[image]

Comment: Dependencies (constructor parameters in this case) are resolved when ASP.NET Core creates the controller instance via [Dependency Injection](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html)

Comment: thanks for the link! help me understand if i'm getting this right.  In the case of my web application the startup class is responsible for adding the services or middle ware I want to use in my application, so in this case the services.AddIdentity and the app.UseIdenty are creating those objects based on things like my database connection string and so forth?  By the way I appreciate your help

Comment: Yup, that's exactly how it works ;). Anything that is registered in `IServiceCollection` either by middleware or by your configuration will be available for you to use as a constructor parameter (and also in other contexts, such as `@inject`in views)

Comment: btw, I found this channel9 series pretty good [aspnetmonsters](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/aspnetmonsters), though there is more and more content (and blogs) everywhere now that .net core is close to RTM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Startup.cs` you will see a call to this method

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
```

Afte reading the links on dependency injection suggested by @AndrésRobinet you can actually see where the services are being wired up.

This extension method lives in [`IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) - You can then go and look at the source code for this method call (.NET core is on github):

line 67 of the `AddIdentity` method

```
services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<TUser>, SignInManager<TUser>>();
```

> what external code is passing in these objects?

Right-click on External code and click `Show External Code` - now you can get an idea of what is happening under the hood. the code down to and including the  Kestrel webserver is also browsable/downloadable on github

[image]

*image truncated*